# how to set default value for angular chosen

Tags: angularjs, angular-chosen

I want to set my angular chosen with default value from my response. also my Angular chosen dropdown values also coming from AJAX response. I tried ng-init and pointing the value with respect to index. But no luck.

HTML

```
   <select  ng-init="model.country = cities[currentLocationIdx]"  
chosen  ng-model="model.country"  
   ng-options=" cities.name for cities in cities" required> 
    <option value="">Select a Location</option> 
    </select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.model.country = "Bangalore";
    $scope.currentLocationIdx = $scope.cities.findIndex( city => city.name ===  $scope.model.country );
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "South Andaman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nicobar"
  },
  {
    "name": "Adilabad"
  },
  {
    "name": "Anantapur"
  },
  {
    "name": "Chittoor"
  },
  {
    "name": "East Godavari"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bangalore"
  }
]
```

Comment: how will you decide which name is default one? There should be one more field for default name.

Comment: User will select there cities in registeration form for example. Now i want to display that as default value as city selected by the user in the form.

Comment: please check y answer

Comment: I am asking about angular chosen. You mentioned about normal select box.

Comment: <select chosen ng-model="setselected" ......> option

Comment: I didnt get your answer

Comment: Did you miss up with city name and country??

Comment: thats just a name given

Comment: Don't use ng-init like this. Set the model.country value in your js after fetching $scope.currentLocationIdx value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare your variable as obj in controller like this:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1n4b2Lfp/260/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this below updated code. Its working at my end with chosen library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" chosen
            ng-options="city.name for city in cities track by city.name"
            ng-model="country"></select>

    {{country}}

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chosen-localytics/1.8.0/angular-chosen.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.cities = [
                  {
                      "name": "South Andaman"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "Nicobar"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "Adilabad"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "Anantapur"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "Chittoor"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "East Godavari"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "Bangalore"
                  }
            ];
            $scope.country = { "name": "Bangalore" };
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am asking query on angular chosen

Comment: Now you will need to set the $scope.country.. Based on its value, the dropdown will choose the default value. It is up to you how you are going to set this value. May be you can call a HTTP service to set this.But make sure you set it in required format.

Comment: And whenever the dropdown selection changes, the value of $scope.country will also change. So make use of this for your further processing.

Comment: I understand the concepts of select . But I am using angular-chosen. Which doesnt set default values.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chosen-localytics/1.8.0/angular-chosen.js"></script>  I'm using this cdn

Comment: for the above edited answer. It takes last value of the array as default value

Comment: No. Its not like that. Its all depends on what you set in $scope.country. In this example, it is choosing the last value, because this variable is set as Bangalore. Try with other options like Adilabad. It should work at your end as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173799/discussion-between-rakesh-burbure-and-nicoleta-wilskon).